# How to make navigation bar stick to the top

Tags: html, css

For some reason `position: sticky` doesn't work. I use w3schools navbar, when you load the page navbar isn't exactly at the top but a little bit lower, I want it to stay on top when i scroll under it. I used this same principle on another page and it worked, the only difference that I can see is on that page it was not child of any elements and now it is.

```css
#nav-bar {
  width: 100%;
}

#nav-bar {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  text-align: center;
}

#nav-bar li {
  display: inline-block;
}

#nav-bar li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-wrapper">
  <header id="header">
    <div class="logo">
      <img id="header-img" src="https://premiumbpthemes.com/images/sneakers-clipart-simple-9.png">
      <h1 class="title">Shoe shop</h1>
    </div>
    <nav id="nav-bar">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="nav-link" href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-link" href="news.asp">News</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-link" href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-link" href="about.asp">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>
```

I tried to style `<ul>` and `<nav>` directly, add class instead of ID but none of these works.
When I searched online I found that it has something to do with `overflow: hidden` but if I delete that my navbar disappears.

Comment: Do you prefer adding Bootstrap?

Comment: codepen.com add your code here so we can play around with it?

Comment: Of course, https://codepen.io/simic21/pen/ExxrwmM @BennKingy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you prefer Bootstrap I would highly recommend you to go with the below code. To make your navigation bar sticky at the top, just add **.fixed-top** class to the **navbar** class.

**Note:** I have used Bootstrap 4. You should use these frameworks to minimize the CSS code as much as possible. This way you can have a clean and good looking UI.

***I have added a container and written a sample text to help you understand how it works. Run the code, and scroll it down. You will see the navbar remains in its position and the text scrolls as we scroll down.***

**Advantage:** If you consider this, you can simply eliminate your CSS class just like that. And the biggest advantage on top of this is you can customize the BS4 classes in your stylesheet. So using Bootstrap is worth!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="height:1500px">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <br>
  <h3>Sticky Navbar</h3> 
</div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark sticky-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Home</a>
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">News</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid"><br>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Last but not the least, credit goes to w3schools.com.

[Scroll Sticky Navigation bar](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_fixed_sticky&stacked=h)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Here's a thing, yes i can use bootstrap but, i'm doing this to practice and understand code better and why some things work and others don't but thank you very much for your answer. @Rohan Rao

Comment: @simic21 You are welcome. Can you tell me what things are not working?

Comment: @simic21,  I found you want the navbar to stick only when we scroll it. I will update my answer and let you know. Please give me some time :)  (I am having my dinner :P )

Comment: No need to hurry, yes i want it to stick at the top when i scroll under it, here's my codepen so you can check it if you want https://codepen.io/simic21/pen/ExxrwmM.

Comment: @simic21 I have updated my answer. Please run the code snippet and you will find your solution. Hope this helps.

Comment: No, it still doesn't work on my site. Navbar works but it does not stick to the top

Comment: Did you use the class ".sticky-top" in navbar class? Also make sure you have written the scripts and links for BS4 CDN in the order mentioned in the reply. It actually matters.

Comment: Yes, i added sticky-top and all 4 links in the order, but it still does not work

Comment: @simic21 Here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/rohan-rao-the-bashful/pen/gOOEqOY   The fonts might have got small, please manage it. Otherwise, mission accomplished! :D

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `position: fixed` to keep an element in place on the screen.
Since you have `top: 0` then making the position `fixed` will cause the nav bar to stick to the top of the screen.

Comment: Yes but that's not the effect i want, when you load a page navbar is a little bit lower and i want it to start sticking only when you scroll under it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this css:

```
#nav-bar{
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Indeed, this makes navbar stick to the top but as i said, i dont want it to be on top when you load page, its a bit lower and i want it to stick only when you scroll under it. @Omi kabira

Comment: You can use absolute and keep the top as per requirement and then, and onscroll you can change posititon from absolute to fixed using jquery css